# не понял синтаксис функционального выражения

Tags: javascript

Всем привет! Объясните, пожалуйста, функциональное выражение по теме "замыкания, область видимости":

```
return function() {
        alert( x );
      };
```

`})(i); </pre>`

Чтобы создать функцию, нужно ее объявить, в фигурных скобках описано то что она выполняет: return function(){код}(i). Как понять переменную i в скобках в конце?

Comment: покажите весь код

Comment: @Pavel Timofeev  Объявление функции заключено в круглые скобки, чтобы получить выражение функции, и это постфиксное выражение  вызывается с аргументом с именем i. То есть функция объявляется и сразу же вызывается.